# XCode Instruments: Time Profiler stops immediately after recording

Tags: xcode, profiling, instruments

Steps to reproducer

1. Producer -> Profile, Cmd+I
2. Select Time Profiler
3. Press record

The profiler immediately stops and the following is shown on the right panel for Recording Info:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Profile build configuration to Debug, it is by default set to Release.

Choose your target -> Edit Scheme -> Select Profile -> Change Build Configuration to Debug

[image]